# Show day and month from epoch timestamp with vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite

I have this vega-lite spec and I'd like to show the day and month in the x axis from an epoch timestamp:

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "1325376000000", "price": 0},
      {"date": "1325462400000", "price": 100},
      {"date": "1325548800000", "price": 30}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "width": "container"
}
```

This is the current result:

[image: vega-lite chart]

I tried using transformations with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

```
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"date": "1325376000000", "price": 0},
      {"date": "1325462400000", "price": 100},
      {"date": "1325548800000", "price": 30}
    ],
    "format": {"parse": {"date": "date:'%Q'"}}
  },
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "type": "ordinal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "width": "container"
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! Why you did not need to add this `format` prop in this other answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74326702/fill-missing-data-with-0-in-specified-date-range-with-vega-lite?

Comment: I think in the other answer the dates could be parsed automatically as they were clearly dates but as these as just long numbers, Vega needs a prompt to tell them to parse as dates.

Comment: I just noticed the values from my example were strings rather than numbers, that's probably why.